# Как спарсить description в android

Tags: android, xml, парсер, rss

Вот сам description. Как вывести все содержимое и куда вывести в android?

```html
<description>
  <![CDATA[<!doctype html>
 <html lang="en" prefix="op: http://media.facebook.com/op#">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="canonical" href="http://ann.az/az/unibanka-yeni-sedr-muavini-secildi/">
 <title>Unibanka yeni sədr müavini seçildi</title>
 <meta property="fb:article_style" content="default">
 </head>
 <body>
 <article>
 <header>
 <!-- The cover image shown inside your article --> 
 <figure>
 <img src="http://ann.az/photo/933x622/2016-11/1478596166_asef_huseynov.jpg" />
 <figcaption>Unibanka yeni sədr müavini seçildi</figcaption>
 </figure>
 
 <!-- The title shown in your article -->
 <h1>Unibanka yeni sədr müavini seçildi</h1>
 
 <!-- The published and last modified time stamps -->
 <time class="op-published" dateTime="2016-11-08T13:12:00+04:00">Tue, 08 Nov 2016 09:12:00 +0000</time>
 <time class="op-modified" dateTime="2016-11-08T13:12:00+04:00">Tue, 08 Nov 2016 09:12:00 +0000</time>
 </header>
 <h1>Unibanka yeni sədr müavini seçildi</h1>
 <p>"Unibank” Kommersiya Bankı” ASC-dən verilən məlumata görə, Səhmdarların Ümumi Yığıncağının qərarına əsasən, İdarə Heyətinin üzvü Asəf Hüseynov Unibank İdarə heyəti sədrinin müavini təyin edilib.&nbsp;
 
 
 Qeyd edək ki, Asəf Hüseynov hazırda bankın Baş risk inzibatçısıdır.
 
 
 Asəf Hüseynov Unibank komandasına qoşulmazdan əvvəl başqa kommersiya bankında müxtəlif vəzifələrdə, sonra isə Mərkəzi Bankda fəaliyyət göstərib.
 
 
 Unibank kollektivi Asəf Hüseynova yeni vəzifəsində uğurlar arzulayır!www.ann.az</p>
 
 
 
 <footer>
 <!-- Copyright details for your article -->
 <small>© Ann.az</small>
 </footer> 
 </article>
 </body>
 </html>]]>
</description>
```